# Can robocopy detect changes in Stata's *.dta files?

Tags: stata, robocopy

I'm trying to automate my backups with robocopy.

I'm using a command:

```
ROBOCOPY <souce_dir> <dest_dir> /MIR /XD D
```

Everything works as it should apart from the fact that when I re-run the command moment later it copies all [Stata's *.dta](http://www.stata.com/help.cgi?dta) files again.

Is there any way araound this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be working fine for me. My example directory contains a **.pdf,**
a **.do** file, a **.dta** file, and a directory named **D**. The first run copies everything
except the **D** directory, as expected. The second run copies nothing, as
expected. If I'm not understanding your problem correctly, let me know. Below
the output of both runs.

(My ROBOCOPY is the version shipped with Windows 7, 64 bits.)

**First run**

```
RFERRER C:\Users\rferrer>ROBOCOPY D:\Datos\rferrer\Desktop\desk1 D:\Datos\rferre
r\Desktop\desk2 /MIR /XD D

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Wed Mar 26 16:14:22 2014

   Source : D:\Datos\rferrer\Desktop\desk1\
     Dest : D:\Datos\rferrer\Desktop\desk2\

    Files : *.*

 Exc Dirs : D

  Options : *.* /S /E /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           3    D:\Datos\rferrer\Desktop\desk1\
100%        New File                6442        auto.dta
100%        New File               17606        CartaAnualRegular.pdf
100%        New File                 950        statfile.do

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         2         0         2         0         0         0
   Files :         3         3         0         0         0         0
   Bytes :    24.4 k    24.4 k         0         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00


   Speed :              595190 Bytes/sec.
   Speed :              34.057 MegaBytes/min.

   Ended : Wed Mar 26 16:14:23 2014
```

**Second run**

```
RFERRER C:\Users\rferrer>ROBOCOPY D:\Datos\rferrer\Desktop\desk1 D:\Datos\rferre
r\Desktop\desk2 /MIR /XD D

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Wed Mar 26 16:15:01 2014

   Source : D:\Datos\rferrer\Desktop\desk1\
     Dest : D:\Datos\rferrer\Desktop\desk2\

    Files : *.*

 Exc Dirs : D

  Options : *.* /S /E /COPY:DAT /PURGE /MIR /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

                           3    D:\Datos\rferrer\Desktop\desk1\

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

               Total    Copied   Skipped  Mismatch    FAILED    Extras
    Dirs :         2         0         2         0         0         0
   Files :         3         0         3         0         0         0
   Bytes :    24.4 k         0    24.4 k         0         0         0
   Times :   0:00:00   0:00:00                       0:00:00   0:00:00

   Ended : Wed Mar 26 16:15:01 2014
```

Comment: Thanks for chasing this @Roberto. It looks like the only difference between our setups are the fact that I'm on Win Server 2008 & backing up to a network drive.. Still - `.dta` issue remains :/ Perhaps it's the size of the file that is the issue (I tested with ~1.8GB).